# Push metor app to the online git remote

Tags: meteor, git-push

After doing: `$ meteor deploy myapp.meteor.com` how can I push new changes so that it update the version that is on line (myapp.meteor.com) ?

How can I push to the online remote if there is like I would with heroku by doing `git push heroku master` ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do `$ meteor deploy myapp.meteor.com` to redeploy your app. There is nothing like `meteor push` or `git push heroku master` in meteor.

> If this is the first time deploying to this hostname, Meteor creates a
>   fresh empty database for your application. If you want to deploy an
>   update, Meteor will preserve the existing data and just refresh the
>   code.

More info here: [Reference](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/deploying)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to wire something up with Travis CI or similar to run `meteor deploy` whenever you receive a git push.